# jQuery retrieve hash and apply it as an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, filter, if-statement

My function checks the URL for a hash, returns it's value, uses that value to find an image (by ID) and apply a class name to it. My console's not showing any errors, but I'm not seeing the expected result.

Instead of filtering the `.z` class by the returned `hash` value, it's writing all of the `.z` class to `id=image`

Is there a better way to filter that value and use it as an ID? Thanks!

JavaScript:

```
(function($){
$.brantley = function(callback) {
    var $doc = $(document),
        $win = $(window),
        $z, $load, $footer, $header, $status, $container, $hash;

    $doc.ready(function() {
        $z          = $('.z');
        $load       = $('#load');
        $footer     = $('footer');
        $header     = $('header');
        $status     = $('#status');
        $container  = $('#container'),
        hash        = gethash();

        if(hash) {
            var image = hash;
            $('.z').attr('id', 'image').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.z:first').addClass('active');
        }

    });

    function gethash() {
        var hash=window.location.hash;
        hash=hash.replace(/#/,'');
        return hash;
    }

    function updateNumber(type) {
        window.location = window.location.pathname + "#" + type;
    }

};
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT:

Took all the comments into consideration as well as the answer, here's what I finished with:

```
(function($){
$.brantley = function(callback) {
    var $doc = $(document),
        $win = $(window),
        $z, $load, $footer, $header, $status, $container;

    $doc.ready(function() {
        $z          = $('.z');
        $load       = $('#load');
        $footer     = $('footer');
        $header     = $('header');
        $status     = $('#status');
        $container  = $('#container');

        var hash = gethash();

        if(hash) {
            $('#' + hash + '.z').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.z:first').addClass('active');
        }

        bromance();
    });

    $win.load(function() {
        bromance();
        $load.fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $('.active').fadeIn('slow');
            $status.fadeIn('slow');
            $footer.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });

    $win.resize(function() {
        bromance();
    });

    function gethash() {
        var hash=window.location.hash;
        hash=hash.replace(/#/,'');
        return hash;
    }

    function updateNumber(type) {
        window.location = window.location.pathname + "#" + type;
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Uh, `var image = hash;` isn't doing anything and your hash object is never used. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You have a syntax error: `$container  = $('#container'),` - the comma should be a semicolon.

Comment: The `hash` variable is missing a `$`. This hash variable is now a global variable, not a local variable. Your `$hash` variable near the top is never actually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not filtering by ID, you are changing the ID. To filter by ID, use this:

```
if(hash) {
    var image = hash;
    $('#' + image + '.z').addClass('active');
} else {
    $('.z:first').addClass('active');
}
```

Or just get rid of that superfluous variable:

```
if(hash) {
    $('#' + hash + '.z').addClass('active');
} else {
    $('.z:first').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Just about to say the same thing. Since there's only one ID per page, why not just `$('#' + hash).addClass('active');`?

Comment: He only wants to select if that element also has the `z` class name, and that way looked simpler. However, since you insist, I'll change it.

Comment: better yet... `$(location.hash + '.z')` :P

Comment: @all: I've thought about all of this, and much more. I mean, what's with the stupid regex? However, in order to not confuse the OP too much, I decided to "go with his flow", and use his code as much as possible...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this line:

```
$('.z').attr('id', 'image').addClass('active');
```

Which says "select all elements with class 'z' and set their 'id' attribute to the string 'image', then add the class 'active'.

What you want to do is this:

```
$('#' + image).addClass('active');
```

Which says "select the element with the id equal to whatever's in the variable `image`, and add the class 'active'.

Note, if you have an id you don't need to select on the class because id is supposed to be unique in the page. You *can* use a selector that has class *and* id, `$('.z#' + image)`, but it is redundant unless you have duplicate ids on the page, and if you *do* have duplicate ids your HTML is invalid and you will not get consistent results across different browsers.

EDIT: if you don't want to change the element unless it has that id *and* the z class then use the `$('.z#' + image)` selector from my last paragraph. Or `$('#' + image + '.z')`.